# node js , mongodb : check if an object already exist

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'am newbie to nodejs and mongodb, so how can I check if an object already exist in the collections , Note that my field type in  the  schema is object or JSON

```
const BillSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {

        content: {
            type: Object //or JSON
        },
    }
);

const Bill = module.exports = mongoose.model('Bill', BillSchema);

module.exports.addBill = function (newBill, callback) {
    //Check for all bill titles and content, if newBill doesn't exist then add else do nothing
    Bill.count({ content: newBill.content }, function (err, count) {
        //count == 0 always ???
        if (err) {
            return callback(err, null);

        } else {
            if (count > 0) {
                //The bill already exists in db
                console.log('Bill already added');
                return callback(null, null);
            } else {   //The bill doesnt appear in the db
                newBill.save(callback);
                console.log('Bill added');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Well there actually are ["upserts"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option) to do this sort of thing. It generally makes most sense when you actually are checking an existing field or a combination of a few to see if they exist though. The single field in here does not make much sense. Are you just putting it in there because you don't know how to use a mongoose schema without defining all the fields?

Comment: No , I do that because I don't have static fields, for every post I have new json format @Neil Lunn

Comment: `new Schema({},{ "strict": false })`. No need to define a schema and no need to shove everything under one key. Still the question to you is **which properties actually identify it is the same object?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One Of Nice Question You asked, I was suppose to achieve the same task before, I make the use of mongoose-unique-validator third party npm Package, & plugin to our schema

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-unique-validator

**npm install mongoose-unique-validator**

```
var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

const BillSchema = mongoose.Schema(

    {
        content: {type:Object , unique:true },
    }
);

BillSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator, {message: 'is already taken.'});
```

Usage:

```
module.exports.addBill = function (newBill, callback) {    
    newBill.save(callback);    
}
```

I Hope If this work for you too.

Comment: thanks for reply, i will try your solution and tell you if (error)

Comment: yes I will , I just have some stuff to do then I will try it, and I will accept your solution if there is no problem , otherwise , I will tel what I have

Comment: @nadhem Can you please let me know is this solution work for you ?
I am facing the same requirement.

Comment: @Hiro solution is working i have double check it, you can use this.